# How to make a loop in a switch with a readline

Tags: ios, swift

I have to make a game for my online course, it displays on the console it's a game for 2 players with 3 characters for each team and I'm struggling how can i make a loop in my switch to "force" the player to choose between 1, 2 or 3 (it symbolize the characters of his team) to attack the enemy team, here's my code :

```
func chooseChar(charac: inout[Character]){
        let choice = readLine()
        var attacker: Character

        switch choice {
        case "1":
            attacker = self.playerTeam[0]
            charac.append(attacker)
        case "2":
            attacker = self.playerTeam[1]
            charac.append(attacker)
        case "3":
            attacker = self.playerTeam[2]
            charac.append(attacker)

        default: print("choose between 1 2 3")
        }

}
```

Actually, when the player choose for example 4 it goes on the default and my code stop...

Anybody have an idea ? sorry for my bad english !

Thanks !

Comment: Add the loop *around* the switch block, not inside it. Then exit the loop only when the choice is not the default case.

Comment: Try to apply validation(to restrict choice less than or equal to 3) to your input field which gets choice from user.

Comment: Ok but how can i restrict a choice for a readline() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a classic C way and add while(true) make things easier like this.

```
func chooseChar(charac: inout[Character]){
    while (true){
        let choice = readLine()
        var attacker: Character

        switch choice {
        case "1":
            attacker = self.playerTeam[0]
            charac.append(attacker)
            return
        case "2":
            attacker = self.playerTeam[1]
            charac.append(attacker)
            return
        case "3":
            attacker = self.playerTeam[2]
            charac.append(attacker)
            return
        default: print("choose between 1 2 3")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement you can call the same function in default case (use recursion)(this will make your code running until any case1,case2,or case3 occurs), or you can set a parameter in default case and check outside the switch and make action according to that.